# jquery - selecting by css class

Tags: jquery, css

new to web.

I am trying to know if user has clicked on div with css a certain class

my class html element is as follows

```
<div class="icon arrowIcon arrowLight tagIcon"></div>
```

my event target value is

```
$(event.target): jQuery.fn.init[1]
   0: div.icon arrowIcon arrowLight tagIcon
```

and the function

```
($(event.target).find('.tagIcon').length > 0)
```

returns false.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` searches the children. You should check if your element has the class you want:

```
$(event.target).hasClass("tagIcon")
```

Answer (score 3):

`find()` finds matching element(s) *inside* the element it is called on. It does not matter if the element itself matches the selector.

Change your check to:

```
($(event.target).is('.tagIcon'))
```